# Change the live stream to vod streaming when Changes

Tags: php, dynamic, stream, live-streaming

I have an online tv website. I've two streaming , one is live streaming , second is Vod Streaming. I setup one control on my site adminpanel for switching over from live to Vod when live streaming become down. I've done this normally using php. The Bellow picture is just Example view for switching the streams.
[image]
As per my php coding if I switch from live to Vod the value stored in one text file. Using 
`file_get_content` I get that value from the text file. But for changing the streaming player on webpage I need to refresh the page. But I want without refershing, Just need to change the streaming player for who are all watching my online TV. thanks advance

Comment: Are you storing value in DB?

Comment: no i am not using DB. Just text file only

Comment: Are you storing the chosen value into text file?

Comment: yes i am chosen text file for store value

Comment: let me know text file structure.

Comment: just text file only . when i was submit the value was stored on file. and get value by file_get_content.

Comment: How the data is being stored in text file? For Eg. Just storing value 0 or 1 for identifying Live or Vod?

Comment: live or vod -> these strings only